What rules TeX uses for space between symbols in equation?
TeX seems to have some rules what space to use between symbols in equation. Here is MWE
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
u'               &  = b B + b C f +a\\
u'               &  = b B f + b C f +a\\
u'               &  = b f C + b C f+a\\
u'               &  = b a C + b C f+a\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}

Compiling with lualatex  gives

Spacing in general seems to change based on letters used and how many in each term.
I am using default font. Does it depend on what font one uses?
What are the main rules of thumb Latex uses to decide on spacing or does it depend on what letter happened to be there?
TL 2024

Let's make an experiment:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$bB$ $bC$ $bf$

\showoutput

\end{document}

Here's the relevant part from \showoutput:
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 B
....\kern0.50172 (italic)
....\mathoff
....\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33 plus 1.665 minus 1.11
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 C
....\kern0.71527 (italic)
....\mathoff
....\glue(\spaceskip) 3.33 plus 1.665 minus 1.11
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764 (italic)
....\mathoff

You can see that no space whatsoever is added between the letters.
For comparison, this is what you get with legacy pdflatex:
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 B
....\kern0.50172
....\mathoff
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 C
....\kern0.71527
....\mathoff
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 b
....\OML/cmm/m/it/10 f
....\kern1.0764
....\mathoff

which is exactly the same.
One might argue that some kerning pairs should be added, but the combinations of math letters are too many.
Another experiment:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$bB$ $bC$ $bf$

\fboxrule=0.1pt
\fboxsep=-0.05pt

\newcommand{\mch}[1]{\fbox{\usefont{OML}{cmm}{m}{it}#1}\kern-0.05pt }

\mch{b}\mch{B}{\kern0.05pt} \mch{b}\mch{C}{\kern0.05pt} \mch{b}\mch{f}

\end{document}


Can you see where your eye gets deceived?

Excellent answer, except for “ One might argue that some kerning pairs should be added, but the combinations of math letters are too many.” Professional text fonts have just as many letters, and typically have kerning wherever necessary; its omission in math fonts seems just a shortcoming/oversight, not infeasible to add by any means.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Typically fonts may have kerning pairs for “uppercase followed by lowercase” or two “same case” letters. And cmmi10 has several kerning pairs. Maybe it's a shortcoming, but a wise writer tries and avoid multiplying b by B or C.

TeX doesn't know the shapes of characters, it manipulates only with their rectangular outlines. It is unable to know a shape collision like shown in your example and like people feel when they are looking to the shapes. The kerning pairs exceptions are designed in fonts for such purposes. But kerning exception between b and C is not implemented in the font cmmi10 (used for math symbols in your example).
